# Plotly Choropleth map successfully loads in Jupyter, but not Dash browser

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, plotly-dash, geopandas

I have been able to successfully create a custom shapefile Choropleth map using plotly and geopandas. It loads successfully in my Jupyter window. The following image is what the map looks like when running in Jupyter.

[Successfully rendered map in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm9LY.png)

This is the code used to render the above map:

```
data = go.Choroplethmapbox(
        geojson = gdf_json,
        locations = df.index.astype(str),
        z = df['2016']['Total'],
        text = df.index.astype(str),
        colorbar=dict(thickness=20,ticklen=3,tickformat=',.2r',outlinewidth=0),
        marker_line_width=0.5,
        marker_opacity=0.4,
        colorscale='gnbu',
        zmin=zmin,
        zmax=zmax,
        hovertemplate = "<b>%{text}</b><br>" +
                    "%{z:,.4r}<br>" +
                    "<extra></extra>")

#mapbox geographic map layout
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Expenditure, 2020',
    autosize=True,
    #hovermode='closest',
    #showlegend=True,
    height=600,
    margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=40, b=0),
    
    mapbox = dict(
        domain = {'x': [0, 1],'y': [0, 1]}, 
        center = dict(lat=-27.628296146695863, lon=152.74025612708698),
        accesstoken = MAPBOX_ACCESSTOKEN, 
        #pitch=0,
        zoom=10,
        style='light')
    )

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

However, when I attempt to load the map into Dash, it returns as an empty graph. (Note I cancel out the `fig.show()` line of code during this process).

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id = 'plot', figure = fig)

])
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

[Unsuccessful map in Dash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wuCf.png)

**What I have tried**

To narrow down the potential problems, I have tried to load in other elements such as dropdowns, radio buttons and a range slider. These loaded successfully, just not the map itself. I am also using the correct public Mapbox API token, as I have previously loaded up a Scattermapbox graph (created a bubble map), which has been successful on Dash.

**Possible reasons**

Obviously the starting point is whether there might be a very small minor syntax error in my code.

However I'm also wondering if there's something wrong with the loading of the geojson? Even though it loads successfully in Jupyter, maybe there is a slightly different method used when loading it into Dash?

To convert my geopandas polygons into geojson:

1. I converted it into an appropriate CRS --> `gdf.to_crs(epsg=4326)`
2. Set the index to my unique id --> `gdf.set_index(id)`
3. Applied this function --> gdf_json = `gdf.__geo_interface__`

[Example of the geojson file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3L1mD.png)

Would love some help if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a very similar problem and when I converted from jupyter to dash I do not recall having to change the process of the geojson. But don't reject that possibility yet. The fact that it isn't producing any errors from the geojson is likely indicative of an error in how you build your layout. So the first two things you should try first.

1. Run the debugger (if you aren't already) because this will pick up on errors that will not be ported to your terminal.

`app.run_server(debug=True)`

2. Put your map rendering code into a function

   `def build_map():`

   ```
    return fig #after building the map figure
   ```

   `app.layout =  html.Div[(dcc.Graph(figure = build_map())]`

I ran into one error with building larger maps where it would time out.

There are so many things that could go wrong here, so process of elimination is key. Feel free to comment below and I will continue to try and help you out!